# Saving a class using non serializable objects to file

Tags: java, serializable

I have created a class using non serializable objects such as ArrayList's, etc... this class implments Serializable but of course when I try to write a class instance to file using the ObjectOutputStream's writeObject method, I get an IOException.
How to avoid this problem? The writeObject method is final so I can't override it, do I have to save manually (reading all the ArrayList's and saving it's elements one per one) the object, or there is a chance to manage writeObject method to work?

P.S.: I think it's not necessary to include since it's not significative for the problem, but if you think it's necessary to post the code (which also contains other user-defined classes, so it's  hard to understand), please let me know.

Comment: `ArrayList` *is* serializable.

Comment: Can you give us the stack trace so we can know which things aren't getting serialized?

Comment: What objects are you storing *in* the `ArrayList`?  Are *they* serialisable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need to override *or* 'provide an implementation`of`writeObject()`.
2. `ArrayList` *is* serializable, as per comment above.
3. You need to read the actual error message you are getting. It's not just 'an IOException', it contains information. Almost certainly it is telling you that some other class isn't serializable. So that's what you have to fix. And doing that doesn't usually involve `writeObject()` methods either.

Comment: I explain what happened: I was using ArrayList of non serializable objects.Such as ArrayList<Location> with Location user-defined class that was not implementing serializable (my bad).

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Exactly so. So the solution lies in fixing the non-serializability of those classes, not in futzing around with a `writeObject()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The writeObject is final but it is also private.  You are not supposed to override it.  You are just supposed to provide an implementation (also private).  It is weird, but that is how it is.

Comment: You aren't 'supposed' to provide an implementation. You may choose to do so. In this case it doesn't appear to be necessary.

Comment: Correct.  For the most part you do nothing with writeObject.  If your class can not be serialized in the usual way (unlikely), you have to provide an implementation of `writeObject` but it would not be overriding anything because it is private.